# How to Highlight Updated Items onRefresh of FlatList

Tags: react-native

I set up a FlatList with an onRefresh function to update the state when the user drags down the screen. It works properly, however I was wondering how I can highlight items in the FlatList that have been updated after the refresh.

Say, for example, I want to change the background for a few seconds for any item in the list that was updated, then return to normal.

```
      <FlatList
        data={scores}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <View style={styles.scoreContainer}>
            <ScoreRow data={item.away} />
            <ScoreRow data={item.home} />
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.gameID}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={updateScores}
      />
```

The best I could do was add a useEffect in the ScoreRow component to detect if something changes within that component, but that only allows me to update one component at a time, not the entire View.

```
  const [runUpdate, setRunUpdate] = useState(false)
  const [runs, setRuns] = useState(data.R)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(runs !== data.R) {
      setRunUpdate(true)
      setRuns(data.R)
      setTimeout(() => setRunUpdate(false), 10000)
    }
  }, [data.R])
```

I can't figure out how to detect a change on an an item in the View of the FlatList so that I can change the entire View the way I did each component.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using data of `FlatList`. You have to make an extra parameter for this.

eg:

```
//Method to refresh data
    _refreshMethod() {
      // Do your code to fetch...
      ...
      let newDataArray = data // Data fetch from server or some thing.
      let updatedArray = []
      newDataArray.map((data, index) => {
            data["isNewItem"] = true;
            updatedArray.push(data);
      });

      this.setState({scores: updatedArray})
      this._callTimer()
    }



// Method to update new item status after a delay
    _callTimer() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          let updatedArray = []
          this.state.scores.map((data, index) => {
                data["isNewItem"] = false;
                updatedArray.push(data);
          });
          this.setState({scores: updatedArray})
      }, 3000); // The time you want to do...
    }
```

Then change the style of row based on the state value.

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.scores}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <View style={item.isNewItem ? styles.yourNewItemStyle :  styles.scoreContainer}>
            <ScoreRow data={item.away} />
            <ScoreRow data={item.home} />
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.gameID}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={updateScores}
        extraData={this.state}
      />
```